# using sprite for background

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I currently have the following:

```
html {
    background-image: url('../bundles/app/img/bg-tile-main.png');
}
```

now since I've put bg-tile-main.png into a sprite.. how can I have the same effect as the above? As far as I have researched I can't repeat background when using sprite?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? -Possible use a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do that yet, in future you will be allowed to use

```
background:image-rect(url('img.png'), 16, 16, 16, 16) repeat top left;
```

currently supported only by Firefox

more info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-image-rect

example on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/moz-image-rect/ (works only on FF atm)

Answer (score 0):

Along with **`background-image`**, you need to give the **`background-position`**.  Then you can repeat a particular image in the spritesheet.

For getting the position, use [**spritecow**](http://www.spritecow.com/),an online tool.

**Updates:**

Here is my sprite image

[image]

```
#rr {
    background: url('http://files.simurai.com/misc/sprite.png') repeat-y -257px -8px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 661px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/4321/)

**FYI:** Where **`repeat-x`** is not working, since the width covers the image specified.

Here is a pretty heck about repeating the `background-position`, 
[**Background repeat and CSS sprites**](http://www.phpied.com/background-repeat-and-css-sprites/)

> The rule is pretty simple: if you want the background to repeat
>   vertically (top to bottom), place the images in the sprite
>   horizontally (left to right) and make sure the individual images in
>   the sprite have the same height. For the opposite case: when you want
>   to repeat horizontally, sprite vertically.

Comment: how do I repeat a particular image in the spritesheet? Example?

Comment: @adit I have added an example, please go through it.